# Expanding a website - providing different contents across different places

Tags: localization

I am working on a website. Currently the website was targeted to serve users from a specific Geographic region. Now I would like to expand its userbase to another region. The need is to serve different contents to different regions with the same base functionality.

My initial thought (I might sound a noob here) is to host the content specific to different regions on different databases -> Redirect users to specific domains and thus map the users geographically. Do suggest if its the right way to proceed.

Also, I would like to know whether there is a need to localize my website for these regions (Current language used is English)

Please post your experiences in such scenarios and also your ideas to bring about the transition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How do you see users being matched to their specific regional content?

1. Will they be presented with an option to choose?
2. Will you use geo functions to determine location?
3. Will you use server based reverse DNS lookup to determine location?
4. Will each region get its own "entry" URL (aka different domains)?

The first three are fraught with their own specific problems...

Presenting a choice/menu is considered bad form because it adds to the number of "clicks" necessary for a user to get to the content they actually came for.

While geo functions are very widely supported in all modern browsers, it is still seen as an issue of privacy in that a large number of users will not "allow" the functionality, meaning you'll have to fallback to a choice/menu approach anyway.

Server based reverse DNS, while a common practice, is very unreliable because many users are using VPN, proxies, TOR, etc. to specifically mask their actual location via this method of lookup.

Personally, my experience is to use completely separate entry URLs that are **all hosted as virtual domains on a single Web Server**. This gives you a large array of methods of determining which entry URL was used to access your code, and then format/customize the content appropriately.

There is really no need to setup separate servers and/or databases to handle these different domains/regions.

With that said, even if the language is common across regions, it is a very good habit to configure your servers and databases to support UTF-8 end-to-end, such that if any language specific options need to be supported in the future, then you won't need to change your code to do so.  This is especially true if your site will capture any user generated input.

Comment: thanks for your detail insight. can you please elaborate on how using virtual domains on a single server would eliminate the need for using different databases as I would like to serve totally different contents to the users based on their geography with the same underlining application features.

Comment: The different content is still just "data", so if you're using the same underlying codebase, then pulling data for one region is just a different key in the same database/data-table/etc.

Comment: Even if you plan to use different code to handle the different regions, you can still use the same database.  Either use different tables, or just build a key pattern that is based on the region.  When code is hosted on the same physical server, I try to use a single database when possible, because you can define a single database connection pool that can be used across different servlets, etc.

Comment: I plan to use the same code for the different regions. I believe with my current database design (especially with many third party packages), I wont be able to adopt the different regions data into a single database without a major restructuring of my code. i do understand the advantage mentioned about usage across different servlets but I am not sure if its implementable in my case.

Comment: I had mentioned that you could also just create a new set of tables for the new region.  That way the dB connections themselves can still be pooled.  Setting up a whole new database is just extreme.

Comment: that is still doable. the problem with this approach is managing the tables created by third party packages. How do you suggest I proceed with that? These plugins would just create their own tables and operate upon them. How do I separate contents in these?

Comment: If you're using the same third party packages across regions, then just let those packages deal with the data storage and retrieval.  It all goes back to using a key based approach for all your variable retrieval and storage.  Let's take quartz, a java library that does scheduling.  If both regions wanted to do scheduling then both regions would just interact with the **same** quartz service, but use a naming/key strategy for interacting with the quartz service thus allowing quartz to use it's same standard tables across regions.